# Fusion Tables missing from Google Drive

Tags: google-fusion-tables, missing-data, google-drive

Many of my Fusion Tables are missing off my Google Drive account, has anyone else experienced, and hopefully resolved, this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The new version of Drive was the issue. I have gone back to the old version and all my files were there.